# how to get the answer of a question from a string or paragraph or article in python

Tags: python, nlp

i got some data fetched out from an URL and i removed out the tags so the web page text remains so how to extract out the answer of the question i asked for

for ex:

input > how to make money?

get the article that tells me how to do so (id did that)

algorithm to get the answer of that question from the text after i removed the tags

```
class online:
def __init__(self,find) -> None:
    self.search = find
    self.urllist = []

def get_url(self):
    for i in search(self.search,num_results=10):
        self.urllist.append(i)
    return self.urllist

def load_html_tags(self):
    obj = data("").load_data_once("data/htmlTags.json")
    return obj


def google_scrape(self) -> str:
    thepage = requests.get(self.get_url()[randint(0,9)]).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
    
    for data in soup(["style","script","head","form","nav","button"]):
        data.decompose()

    return ' '.join(soup.stripped_strings)
```

so what next?

Comment: You have two possibilities: either you use an existing search engine API, like Google (limited number of free queries). Or you have a massive index of all the web pages where you can search directly. the 2nd option is more efficient but more expensive, because you need to own some massive data centers ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is Natural language processing, which is much more advanced for me to do it justice in a single stackoverflow response. Theres a reason Google's search engine is so popular, and that's because stuff like this is a daunting task.

Assuming you want to write an algo, I'd probably search the text for keywords from the question and return a few words above / below anytime that keyword is spotted.